# Move position of div when breakpoint is triggered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout where two divs are side by side when the page is larger than 900px but when the breakpoint is triggered then the divs are displayed ontop of each other.

```
Original layout:
 --------   -------
| div 1  | | div 2 |
 --------   -------

<900px:
 -------
| div 2  |
 -------- 
 -------
| div 1  |
 --------
```

This is really tricky to recreate because div2 has to end up on top of div1.

Current solution (sent via message to me). I'm not too bothered about the specific 900px breakpoint so I just used bootstrap md.

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-4 col-md-push-8'>
      div 2
   </div>
   <div class='col-md-8 col-md-pull-4'>
      div 1
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Comment: Using Bootstrap push and pull solved the problem. Got the solution sent as message. Thanks